# ICMP echo checksum

Tags: network-programming, checksum, icmp

How can I compute the checksum of an ICMP echo request or reply when the checksum should include the data portion, the data portion can be variable sized, and there's no way to anticipate the data size?

Here's [documentation](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg8.htm) on how to compute the checksum of an ICMP header.

> ICMP Header Checksum. 16 bits. 
>   The 16-bit one's complement of the
>   one's complement sum of the ICMP message, starting with the ICMP Type
>   field. When the checksum is computed, the checksum field should first
>   be cleared to 0. When the data packet is transmitted, the checksum is
>   computed and inserted into this field. When the data packet is
>   received, the checksum is again computed and verified against the
>   checksum field. If the two checksums do not match then an error has
>   occurred.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the sender is calculating the checksum, the value is inserted into the zero'd field. The receiver then does the reverse, it pulls out the checksum, zeros the field and computes the checksum with this field set to zeros. It compares the value it calculated to the one it extracted.

Both sides of the transmission calculate the checksum with the field zero'd out.

**Update**

An example of how to perform this calculation exists on this [Scribd presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7074846/ICMP-and-Checksum-Calc), starting on slide 44. I'm also including the relevant example slide below.

> Figure 9.19 shows an example of checksum calculation for a simple
>   echo-request message (see Figure 9.14). We randomly chose the
>   identifier to be 1 and the sequence number to be 9. The message is
>   divided into 16-bit (2-byte) words. The words are added together and
>   the sum is complemented. Now the sender can put this value in the
>   checksum field.

[image: Ping Checksum calculation]

You split the ICMP header and data into 16 bit words (using 0x0000 for the checksum field), get the sum of these words and then the ones complement of the sum. This is then inserted into the checksum field.

Comment: That's not my question. I need to compute the checksum over the entire ICMP message, which can include a variable-sized data portion. How do I know the size of the message over which I compute the checksum?

Comment: I think the better question at this point, is how are you parsing your packets? The packet data should be part of your packet parsing. That would give you the size of the data.

Comment: The data is optional, and for my purposes I don't care what the data is, so I don't parse it at all. But the sender still may have included the data in the checksum, so I need to know the length of the data, so I can include it in my verification of the checksum.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means your implementation isn't complete. You need to know more than the length of the data, you need the data itself. I edited my answer slightly to include more information

Comment: How do I find out the length of the data?

Comment: You'll need to strip out the packet header and the ICMP header. That should leave the ICMP payload for you to work with.

Comment: How long is that payload.

Comment: The maximum size is [65507](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449837/maximum-legal-size-of-icmp-echo-packet)

Comment: The description how the sender calculates the checksum is correct. For the receiver however it’s much simpler: it doesn‘t have to extract the checksum, set the field it to zero, calculate the checksum and compares his calculation with the extracted value. The receiver just calculates the checksum over the whole icmp packet. If the result is 0, then all is okay. This works as the sender includes the inverted checksum in the packet.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the ICMP message length by subtracting the size of the IP header from the "Total length" field in the IP header.

Comment: is there any proof of that?

Comment: An ICMP packet consists of an IP header and an ICMP message. RFC 792, describes the Total Length field as "Length of internet header and data in octets." For an ICMP packet, the data is the ICMP message.

Comment: Ops, I thought you were talking about checksum. But you're question is about checksum.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that in IPv6, a pseudo header of the IPv6 header, is also included in the checksum calculation. In IPv4 this is not done, because the header already checksums itself.